# Check if a value in hashmap already exists

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates

I ve created a hashMap which contains String values. I want every time that I add a new value to map to check if already exists in hashmap. I have defined

`final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
 map.put(key, myURL.toString());`

How could I loop through the hashmap to check if a duplicate exist?

Comment: If you have a one to one relationship between keys and values, using a BiMap would be more efficient.

Comment: A main purpose of HashMaps is to prevent O(n) fetches.  Also, this question is easily answered by reading the API docs.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html  Learn to read them, learn to love them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`map.containsKey(key)`

`map.containsValue(val)`

If you insist on iterating, do:

```
Iterator<Entry<String, String>>iterator=map.entrySet();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
  final Entry<String, String>next=iterator.next();
  next.getKey(); next.getValue();
}
```

> Specified by:
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 13):

Simple:

```
return map.containsValue(myURL.toString());
```

for example. Or, using java8 streams:

```
return map.values().stream().anyMatch(v -> v.equals(myURL.toString()))
```

But as you ask for *efficient* solutions, I suggest you go with the old-school non stream version. Because the second version is most likely using noticeably more CPU cycles.

Only if your map has *zillions* of entries, and you are looking at **response time** only, then maybe using `parallelStream()` could give you the answer more **quickly**.

Answer (score 2):

`map.containsValue` method is what you need. See [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check the class javadocs, you'll see that there are two methods contains key and containsvalue
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean result = selections.values().stream().anyMatch(Boolean::booleanValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of efficiency, the existence of this data structure is a proof of inefficiency and bad design. `containsValue(V)` is the method you're looking for